# Clicking on a product on a category page just routes me back to the parent category

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, category-products

In my Magento 2 store whenever I click on a product in a category page I get routes to the parent category page instead of going to the product page. Is this a url rewrite issue? Duplicates?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the output of `select * from url_rewrite;` and `select * from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. There were old 301 redirects in the htaccess file that conflicted with what the system rewrites were doing.